# PHP parser/execution order, classes extending classes defined later in file

Tags: php

```
<?php
class B extends A
{
    public $attribute2;
    function operation2()
        {
            echo 'operation2';
        }
}
$b = new B();
$b->operation1();
$b->operation2();
class A
{
    public $attribute1;
    function operation1()
        {
            echo 'operation1';
        }
}
```

It shows the output: `operation1operation2`

Question:

I put the `class A{}` at the end of script, so when it goes to the first line `class B extends A` I thought it will show an error message, something like `undefined class A`, but it does not, why?

Comment: You have to put class A before class B. If you separate the class into few external PHP files, you have to include parent class ( class A ) first , or use `autoload`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order in which you define those classes in the file does not matter.  PHP does not simply go through your script line by line.  It will parse the whole file, load any classes, and execute the procedural code.

If I remember correctly, this hasn't always been the case.  I think PHP 3 had difficulty with this.

Comment: According to [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php), this is not the case: "*if a class extends another, then the parent class must be declared before the child class structure*".  Of course, this is the PHP docs we're talking about...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth and this is the case if you define it a different file and there is no autoloader in play.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, Interesting.  I've never had trouble with it being in the same file... but I haven't done much experimentation either, as I always keep my classes in separate files and use autoloaders.  I wonder if this behavior can be relied upon.

Answer (score 0):

Because PHP is Interpreted Languages, it will precompile some code. such as 'include' , 'require' , it will precomplie also